# Logging Postgres startup errors on Windows

Tags: postgresql, logs

I have been experimenting with Postgres configuration parameters and noticed that when I use settings that prevent Postgres from starting nothing shows up in the pg_log directory logs. I have

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
```

Is there a way to cause Postgres to log startup errors to pg_log on Windows 7 and Postgres 9.3?

Comment: Well, that's job for the windows event log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a chicken-and-egg problem there.

PostgreSQL reads `postgresql.conf` to decide where to log, and how.

So it cannot really log errors in `postgresql.conf` to the PostgreSQL logs, unless it uses some kind of fallback/default log.

Instead, it uses the Windows Event Log, which is what Windows applications are supposed to do anyway. (You can have PostgreSQL write *all* logs to the Windows Event Log if you prefer, by changing its logging configuration).

So you should look in the windows event log - see the Event Viewer - for startup issues with PostgreSQL.